# How can we create a Windows 8 Application which supports in all resolutions?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Which is  the best approach to create a windows 8 application which `supports all resolutions` including `Snapped & Filled States` .

[1366 X 768
1024 X 768
1920 X 1080
2560 X 1440
1280 X 800
1920 X 1080
2560 X 1440]

I tried with 1366 x 768 as base resolution.

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource SEBgColorBrush}">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Height="768" Width="1366" >
        //content 
        </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

But it is `not supported` by 2 resolutions [1024 X 768 & 1280 X 800].

Can anyone have any idea to do this ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx

Answer (score 4):

the built in sample apps do a pretty good job of using visualstate, LayoutAwarePage to support the various resolutions and layouts.

Ideally you wouldn't be doing anything to hardcode height or width, you'd be using the various layout systems to place things in relative positions and resize gracefully, instead of explicitly setting sizes and locations.

Comment: What about Snapped & Fill ? Do we want to give specific width for it by visual state ? For example 320 pixel Width for Snapped State

Comment: is snapped 320 pixels on every size monitor?  on a 30" monitor with a huge resolution, is it still 320px?